# How redirected page that does not exist to my 404 file with this routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I'm new here and sorry if something is wrong. I found this route somewhere and it does a great job but when I go to localhost/blablabal there is just a white page and it doesn't redirect to my 404 error file

index.php file

```
<?php

include 'route.php';

$route = new Route();

$route->add('/', function() {
    require('config/home_l.php');
});

$route->add('pretraga', function() {
    require('config/pretraga.php');
});

$route->submit();
```

route.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * @author      Jesse Boyer <contact@jream.com>
 * @copyright   Copyright (C), 2011-12 Jesse Boyer
 * @license     GNU General Public License 3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/)
 *              Refer to the LICENSE file distributed within the package.
 *
 * @link        http://jream.com
 *
 * @internal    Inspired by Klein @ https://github.com/chriso/klein.php
 */

class Route
{
    /**
    * @var array $_listUri List of URI's to match against
    */
    private $_listUri = array();
    
    /**
    * @var array $_listCall List of closures to call 
    */
    private $_listCall = array();
    
    /**
    * @var string $_trim Class-wide items to clean
    */
    private $_trim = '/\^$';
        
    /**
    * add - Adds a URI and Function to the two lists
    *
    * @param string $uri A path such as about/system
    * @param object $function An anonymous function
    */
    public function add($uri, $function)
    {
        $uri = trim($uri, $this->_trim);
        $this->_listUri[] = $uri;
        $this->_listCall[] = $function;
    }
    
    /**
    * submit - Looks for a match for the URI and runs the related function
    */
    public function submit()
    {   
        $uri = isset($_REQUEST['uri']) ? $_REQUEST['uri'] : '/';
        $uri = trim($uri, $this->_trim);

        $replacementValues = array();

        /**
        * List through the stored URI's
        */
        foreach ($this->_listUri as $listKey => $listUri)
        {
            /**
            * See if there is a match
            */
            if (preg_match("#^$listUri$#", $uri))
            {
                /**
                * Replace the values
                */
                $realUri = explode('/', $uri);
                $fakeUri = explode('/', $listUri);

                /**
                * Gather the .+ values with the real values in the URI
                */
                foreach ($fakeUri as $key => $value) 
                {
                    if ($value == '.+') 
                    {
                        $replacementValues[] = $realUri[$key];
                    }
                }
                
                /**
                * Pass an array for arguments
                */
                call_user_func_array($this->_listCall[$listKey], $replacementValues);
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
ErrorDocument 404 localhost/404.php
```

I remove RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L] from .htaccess and work but how to make all this work without delete this. Sorry for my bad eng..

Comment: As far as your web server is concerned, everything will be redirected to `index.php` via `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]`. At that point, you have to handle missing routes by yourself.

Comment: As GuidoFaecke suggests, you need to handle the 404 in PHP. (You're not doing anything when the requested URL is not found in `$_listUri`.) The Apache `ErrorDocument` is irrelevant here (it also looks malformed the way you have written it.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.